# getting this error AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal 'open_group'

Tags: javascript, postman

```
const jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
})
//each month on the payment day, next_cycle is updated
pm.test("User credit source information are correct", function () {
    pm.expect(jsonData.learner_type).to.eql("B2B");
    pm.expect(jsonData.product_type).to.eql("open_group");
    pm.expect(jsonData.credits).to.have.property('total_available');
    pm.expect(jsonData.subscription.next_cycle).to.eql("2022-11-19");
    pm.expect(jsonData.subscription.type).to.eql("unlimited");
     pm.expect(jsonData.operating_model).to.eql("fixed");
    pm.expect(jsonData.credits.expiry).to.eql("2022-11-19");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

"expected undefined" means that `jsonData.product_type` attribute doesn't exist.

If you do `console.log(jsonData)` you will see that there is not `product_type` key.

Maybe it's a bug in your API; maybe it's a problem on your call....